# Need to open links in new tab in ie8 !

Tags: url, iframe, tabs, hyperlink, internet-explorer-8

I have a sidebar (right sided iframe) and when i click on a link in it, it opens a new window in IE8, (in firefox it open a new tab). What do i need to do to open links in IE8 in a new tab. I already set the Tools->Internet Options->Settings-> **'Always open pop-ups in a new tab'** and **'A new tab in the current window'** open in new tab but still doesn't work. My links are pretty simple, what am i missing ? exemple: [**text**](http://url.com). Also some site are saying to **register Regsvr32 actxprxy.dll** to fix this problem, still doesn't work. And i want this to work with a simple click, no 'right-click->open in new tab' option. I also hope i won't get the 'can't change how ie8 works' answer. ;)

Here is a test file, but still not working with _blank...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        </head>
    <body>
    <a href="http://www.google.ca" target="_blank">open in new tab</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my ie8 parameters for tabs...
[alt text http://db.tt/lMhAs3](http://db.tt/lMhAs3)

And sorry if it's all in french, i'll fix the language later.

Comment: please include some example html including what target parameter you are using in your links :)

Comment: Hmmm...pretty strange that it is not opening in a new tab after adding the target="_blank" attribute and changing your browser settings.  I cannot reproduce the mis-behavior so I will be of little further help.  You might want to post the same question on SuperUser.com to see if anyone there has run into the same issue with IE8.

Comment: Pretty strange indeed. Just posted it on superuser.com.

Comment: Good luck!  Let me know when you get it solved.  Just comment on my answer below so I'll know.  Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the [target="_blank"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute to make links open in a new window or tab.  Where the link actually opens is up to the browser settings.  So if you have Tools > Internet Options > Tabbed Browsing Settings > "Always open pop-ups in new tabs" selected, a target="_blank" link will open in a new tab.  Note that this type of link will open in a new window by default on most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings look right, just loose the "[Target](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp)" attribute in the html
The target attribute defines where the linked document will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Just a short observation, IE (all versions) will not open a link with invalid ULR address. For example a missing slash (http:/domain.ext). It will work on other browsers tho.