# target="_blank" opens a new window in IE9, instead of a new tab

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, anchor

In my link, I have `target="_blank"` attribute, and it works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and of course, Safari and opens the link a new **TAB**. But When I click on it, in IE9 (and IE8) it opens a new window instead of being opened in a new tab. What should I do?

Comment: I think you can change that in the IE9 settings.

Comment: All answers were kind'ev correct. Thanks from all.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

HTML and JavaScript provide no means to say if a new "window" should be a full window, or a tab, or whatever you want to call the Mobile Safari multiple views interface.

So you live with it.

Answer (score 9):

You can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883432/need-to-open-links-in-new-tab-in-ie8) question that the `target="_blank"` is correct, but the way the browser handles this case is up to his settings.

You **need** to change **IE8/9 settings** to open that kind of target in a new tab. There's nothing you can do :|

Answer (score 5):

This is configured browser side and theres nothing you can do about it in your html I'm afraid. Its just an option that a user sets in their browsers preferences.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `target="_blank"` attribute to make links open in a new window or tab. Where the link actually opens is up to the browser settings. So if you have *Tools > Internet Options > Tabbed Browsing Settings > "Always open pop-ups in new tabs"* selected, a `target="_blank"` link will open in a new tab. Note that this type of link will open in a new window by default on most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking Protected Mode in IE9 resolved my problem.

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. When Protected Mode is enabled and a webpage contains an anchor link with a named target, Windows Internet Explorer opens the target of the link in a new window when the target has a different integrity level than the webpage containing the link.

Source: [target attribute in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For me I did the opposite, client had the site in their trusted sites lists (which disables protected mode). So we asked her to remove the site from the list making it revert to the internet zone (which has protected mode on). So... ie is stupid.