# Window.open creates new tabs not popups when parameters are fully functional

Tags: javascript

I've seen lots of questions asking how to open a tab with window.open, but I want the opposite.  When clicking a link, I want a fully functioning new window, (not missing its address bar or anything), not a new tab.

I've been using this:

```
window.open('http://example.com', 'blah', 'titlebar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,status=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=800,height=600,top=10,left=10');
```

In FF i get new windows as popups.  In Chrome (and IE9), it opens as a new tab.

If I set status=0, i get popups, but its not a normal window in chrome (but is in IE9).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tell JS or a HTML action to open a link in a new tab vs. a new window. It's totally browser dependent.

Duped on SO [target="_blank" opens a new window in IE9, instead of a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661696)

IE settings: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-internet-explorer-to-open-links-in-a-new-window-automatically/5222050

Chrome settings on super user: https://superuser.com/questions/166479

Firefox settings on mozilla support: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings