# Open Link in New Tab on AJAX success - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to open a link in new tab after the success method has been called.

Since, I am working for the project, I couldn't share the code. But I am sharing my scenario.

**HTML Part:**

```
<button id="news" onclick="getNews()">Get News</button>
<a href="#" id="newTabLink" target="_blank" ></a>
```

**Javascript Part**

```
function getNews(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "controllerName/actionMethod", 
         success: function(result){

                    //Assigning url to href
                    $('#newTabLink').href(result.url);

                    // Clicking the hyperlink
                    $('#newTabLink').click();
                   }
  });

}
```

**My Scenario of the page:**

On clicking the *Get News* button, it will fetch news from the database if there is any news present. Otherwise, it will show a pop-up on the ***same screen*** like "**News not found**".

Now, if there is any news present then, it will return the URL in ajax success method and ***I want to open it in new tab*** and **not in new window**.

***NOTE:*** I don't want to use **`async:false`** in `ajax` setup. Since it stops the page until the response came from the server.

**What I tried:**

I tried to create an **hyperlink** on page loading(***statically***) and I assigned the `href` in that link on ajax success . After href is assigned, I am clicking that hyperlink.

**My problem:**

*It is opening in new window not in new tab.*

I want to open it in new tab without **`async:false`** and also **note** that, ***I don't want to open the new tab at the first of the button click and setting the timeout***. That will become awkward for my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: In that, which one do you prefer for my scenario?. I found nothing matches my scenario. Could you please tell me that?

Answer (score 0):

Source [target="_blank" opens a new window in IE9, instead of a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661696/target-blank-opens-a-new-window-in-ie9-instead-of-a-new-tab)
May be check your browser settings , target_blank usually opens a new tab these days.
Explanation for IE
You need to use the target="_blank" attribute to make links open in a new window or tab. Where the link actually opens is up to the browser settings. So if you have Tools > Internet Options > Tabbed Browsing Settings > "Always open pop-ups in new tabs" selected, a target="_blank" link will open in a new tab. Note that this type of link will open in a new window by default on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs.

Bootstrap docs.

```
$('#myTabs a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
```

Comment: I don't get you. Could you please explain me?

Comment: Can you simply explain your situation? If you click "a" button tab property is showed.