# Click on hyperlink opens page in new tab and current tab both

Tags: html, hyperlink, tabs

I have a set of hyperlinks in a `HTML` page.
When I click on any hyperlink, it is opening in new tab and current tab both. Which triggers the message `The web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab.`

Note: I have done the IE setting to open links in new tab. I am using below code for all hyperlinks to open in new tab.
 I have tried using `_blank` and `_new` taget options. But somehow nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You have said you have tried with `_bkank` but it should be `target="_blank"`.

BTW, You can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883432/need-to-open-links-in-new-tab-in-ie8) that the `target="_blank"` is correct, but the way the browser handles this case is up to his settings.

You need to `change IE8/9 settings` to open that kind of target in a new tab. There's nothing you can do.

Reference it [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661696/target-blank-opens-a-new-window-in-ie9-instead-of-a-new-tab) as VAShhh's answer.

**UPDATE**

`Possible Reasons for the Behavior:` the web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab

Internet Explorer introduced a wide range of security features with its seventh version. This is the primary reason you face problems when dealing with websites or services having their own security features. The following are some reasons why you get the popup message.

- The problem of a webpage trying to close a window in Internet Explorer is common when you are trying to access a Microsoft Dynamics CRM website.
- It may also happen due to JavaScript errors in the website code.
- Some websites close the Internet Explorer as part of their security policy - to erase the history (eg NetBanking, shopping sites, etc). Unlike with other websites, the popup appears after you log out of the portal.
- A corrupt installation of Internet Explorer can also be the problem.
- The problem also occurs if the Internet Explorer is not current with the security certificates and other IE updates.

The above list is not exhaustive. There may be other reasons. The listed ones are known issues that I came across while working on Internet Explorer. The following sections offer some possible solutions to remove the popup message.

The complete documentation and how to prevent [this is here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/118170.aspx)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: This seems to be some specific setting for my URLs i am putting in HTML page. When i use http://www.google.com it works fine as expected. It opens in a new tab. But when i click on my URLs, it goes to a new tab , shows popup "The page you are trying to view is trying to close the window, do you want to proceed Yes/no", If i click on yes, then it turns my source and destination page both into destination page. Please help.

Comment: I tried turning off protected mode, but still it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried after settings then restart and clearing IE browser clearing catch and history? You got this error in which IE version or all versions? If still you have problem show your code and also provide link of your webpage if possible.