# IE9 opening some links in new tab but some in new window

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, window.open

It's pretty weird that with the same HTML in place, IE9 is opening some links in a new window but others in a new tab.

The below ones are being opened in a new window.

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.gmail.com', target='_blank')" type="button">Gmail</button>
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.wikipedia.org', target='_blank')" type="button">Wikipedia</button>
```

And the below link is being opened in a new tab.

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', target='_blank')" type="button">Google</button>
```

IE9 Version I am using : 9.0.8112.16421

In the tabbed browsing settings, I have selected "Let Internet Explorer decide how pop-ups should open"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Refer to `Bradley Mountford's` answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883432/need-to-open-links-in-new-tab-in-ie8

Comment: @JohnStephen : That's understood, John. The usage of target attribute as '_blank' should open the link in a new window but it's ultimately upto the browser settings to decide as to how it would react.
My question is that keeping the same browser settings and the same HTML, why the browser is responding in different ways for different URLs ?

Comment: You can use the `target-new` property. See my answer below.